# How do I access params in Rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing my first real app in Rails 4. Here are my models...

```
class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end

class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instructor
  belongs_to :tutor
end

class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
end
```

I generally manually set my foreign key relations in my controller like so...

## app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb

```
 def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    @ticket.instructor = params[:instructor_id]
    @ticket.tutor = params[:tutor_id]
    ...
```

I have used this convention in the past with Rails 3...but this does not work in Rails 4. I am guessing because of strong parameters. I tried using something like...

```
@ticket.instructor = ticket_params[:instructor_id]
```

...but this does not work. No error, just nothing gets saved. Here is some console output...

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"afnbX2Ph2aaNj7CDnbcDI9EdA74xBBSV7oSoU4uYZ2Y=", "tutor_id"=>{"id"=>"2"}, "ticket"=>{"session_type"=>"Severe", "student"=>"John Q. Student", "student_id"=>"09098", "course_id"=>"English 111", "notes"=>""}, "instructor_id"=>{"id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Create Ticket"}
```

...as you can see the instructor and tutor ids are being send in the params. However I did a puts/inspect on  ticket_params...

```
{"session_type"=>"Severe", "student_id"=>"09098", "student"=>"John Q. Student", "course_id"=>"English 111", "notes"=>""}
```

...and the instructor and tutor ids are not there. Ideas?

## EDIT

ticket_params method was created by default in my controller. Here it is...

```
 def ticket_params
      params.require(:ticket).permit(:tutor_id, :session_type, :student_id, :student, :instructor_id, :course_id, :notes)
 end
```

Comment: Please, paste your `ticket_params` method.

Comment: Yes, you have a `ticket_params` method somewhere that is creating the hash for you, this is not done by rails automatically.

Comment: when you say there's no error, do you mean there's no exception or that the record has no errors, ie passed all validations?

Comment: @jvnill I can create a new ticket, but the instructor and tutor ids are not saved to the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a method called `ticket_params` in the controller. Something like the following

```
def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:name, :date)
end
```

The method above basically tells the controller that it expects a `params[:ticket]` to be present and the keys passed to the model will only be `:name` and `:date`.  Read more on the [github repo](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters)

**UPDATE: (after ticket_params method was added to the question)**

Change

```
@ticket.instructor = params[:instructor_id]
@ticket.tutor = params[:tutor_id]
```

to

```
@ticket.instructor_id = params[:instructor_id][:id]
@ticket.tutor_id = params[:tutor_id][:id]
```

Comment: see ticket_params above.

Comment: You got my 98% where. I just needed     @ticket.instructor_id = params[:instructor_id][:id] I fixed your answer above. Thanx!

Comment: i've got to remind you though, that code is error prone. it expects to have an `instructor_id` and `tutor_id` hash in the params.  you're better off just passing them as just ids.

Comment: Not sure I'm following you. If I use @ticket.instructor_id = params[:instructor_id] nothing gets saved. params[:instructor_id] is actually a hash that looks like {"id"=>"1"}

Comment: ah no. i'm not saying that. given your current params, your solution is what's needed.  i'm just saying that it's better to change your form so that you only need `params[:instructor_id]` and not `params[:instructor_id][:id]`.  i guess `params[:instructor][:id]` is also better.